# Piping images to avconv at unknown fps

Tags: libav

I am currently reading images from a camera "as fast as possible" (>50fps), outputting them as JPEGs, and piping them to `avconv` using the image2pipe input. What is a good approach to getting the output stream to be as "real time" as possible? Do I instead need to get the output to be a specific frame rate? I had hoped `avconv` could handle that for me, dropping frames as needed.

This is the command I am currently using:

```
avconv -re -f image2pipe -codec:v mjpeg -i - -f flv -codec:v libx264 \
-profile:v baseline -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -an -f mpegts \
udp://localhost:9090
```